# Outlook mails not showing alt and title text in html mails

Tags: html, image, email, outlook

```
<a href="mailto:Abc@xy.com?Sbuject=Yes">
<img src="cid:#appr" width="5" width="20" alt="Alternate" title="Title" />
```

cid:#appr is being embedded using server code to send the image embedded in the mail.
On mouse hover the balloon text does not display alt or title. Instead it displays href value.

Comment: I think this is explicitly done by the mail client in order to _protect_ the user. You could simply have a fishing email and set the alt text to the **valid** url. e.g. a valid banking website.

Comment: @Ramon Thanks, I got similar information at an MS site. If you could put it in answers i would accept it and mark question as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explicitly done by the mail client in order to protect the user.

You could simply create a phishing email and set the 'alt' text to the **valid** url. e.g. a valid banking website.

The user would never know, and is (more) vulnerable.